# Freeing C Stack & Removing Dangling Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, memory-management, destructor

I've implemented a stack in C, using a stackADT struct and a set of functions:

```
#ifndef _stack_h
#define _stack_h

// Macros
#define MaxStackSize 100
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// The type of element that may 
// be stored in the stack
typedef int stackElementT;

// The stackADT represents the abstract type used to store
// the elements that have been pushed
typedef struct stackCDT
{
    // A pointer to an array of elements
    stackElementT* elements;
    // Number of elements on the stack
    int count;
    // Number of elements we can push onto
    // the stack before having to resize
    int size;
}* stackADT;

// This function allocates and returns a new stack, which is
// initially empty... AKA - The Constructor
stackADT NewStack(void)
{
    // The stack to return
    stackADT stack;

    // Instanitate a new stack
    stack = (stackCDT*)(malloc(sizeof(stackCDT)));

    // Start with 0 elements of course
    stack->count = 0;
    // Allocate memory for 50 integers
    stack->elements = (stackElementT*)(malloc(50*sizeof(stackElementT)));
    // Establish the size of the stack
    stack->size = 50;

    return stack;
}


/********* GETTER FUNCTIONS *********/
// Returns the number of elements currently pushed 
// onto the stack
int StackDepth(stackADT stack)
{
    return (stack->count);
}

// This function returns the element a the specified index in
// the stack, where the top is defined as index 0
stackElementT GetStackElement(stackADT stack, int index);

// Function to print contents of stack
void PrintStack(stackADT stack)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("count = %d\nsize = %d\n",stack->count,stack->size);

    for(i = (stack->count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if((i%10 == 0) && (i != 0))
            printf("\n");
        printf("%d\t",*(stack->elements + i));
    }
}


// Functions to determine if stack is empty or full
int StackIsEmpty(stackADT stack)
{
    if(stack->count == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int StackIsFull(stackADT stack)
{
    if(stack->count == stack->size)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


// This function pushes the specified element onto the stack
void Push(stackADT stack, stackElementT element)
{
    // A temporary array that we may use later on
    stackElementT* temp = NULL;
    int oldCount = stack->count;
    int i = 0;

    // If the stack if full we need to do a
    // a transfer, resize, and retransfer, then push
    if(StackIsFull(stack))
    {
        // temp will be the same size as the old stack
        temp = (stackElementT*)(malloc((oldCount)*sizeof(stackElementT)));

        // Now we perform the transfer
        for(i = 0; i < oldCount; i++)
        {
            *(temp + i) = *((stack->elements) + i);
        }

        // Free the old memory
        free(stack->elements);
        stack->elements = NULL;

        // Recreate the stack with a 50% increase in size/capacity
        stack->elements = (stackElementT*)(malloc((3*oldCount/2)*sizeof(stackElementT)));
        // Re-establish the size
        stack->size = 3*oldCount/2;

        // Now we perform the transfer back
        for(i = 0; i < oldCount; i++)
        {
            *((stack->elements) + i) = *(temp + i);
        }

        // Free the temp array and 
        // remove dangling pointer
        free(temp);
        temp = NULL;

        // Now we push the element onto the stack
        *((stack->elements) + oldCount) = element;
        // Increase the count
        stack->count = oldCount + 1;
    }
    // If the stack isn't full
    else
    {
        *((stack->elements) + oldCount) = element;
        stack->count = oldCount + 1;
    }

}

// This function pops the top element from the stack and returns
// that value
stackElementT Pop(stackADT stack);


// This function frees the storage associated with the stack
void FreeStack(stackADT stack)
{
    // Start by freeing the elements on the stack
    // and remove dangling pointers
    free(stack->elements);
    stack->elements = NULL;

    // Finally free the stack
    free(stack);
    stack = NULL;
}

#endif
```

Obviously I'm not completely finished (needs a pop function). My concern is with the bottom function (FreeStack). I tested the code below as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Stack.h"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main(void)
{
    stackADT stack;
    int i = 0;

    stack = NewStack();
    PrintStack(stack);

    for(i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        Push(stack,i);
    }

    PrintStack(stack);
    FreeStack(stack);

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```

The _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() function is for Visual Studio and it indicates if there is a memory leak. Apparently I've sealed off any leaks when calling the FreeStack(stackADT stack) function. However, the stack pointer still holds a memory address, which is the issue because the FreeStack function is supposed to free the memory pointed to by the stack variable and set it equal to NULL. This occurs within the function, but when I return to the main function during debugging, I see the memory address still there. What is it I'm missing here? If I'm able to release the memory, why can't I remove the dangling pointer?

Comment: Not related to your stack freeing question but why do you move elements __twice__ when you resize the stack? It's simpler to allocate a new, larger, memory chunk, move the existing elements once, and assign the new pointer to your struct.

Comment: You shouldn't define the functions in the header files. The definition should be provided in the corresponding source file.

Comment: @Blastfurnace You're absolutely right!!!

Comment: @Saurabh I had another question similar to that, but this was C++. I like to carry old habits from other programming languages. Anyway, it's not like I'm working with a team, this is just for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the stack to the function by value, instead of by address, modify the function to receive (stackADT *) and you'll be good to go.

*Clarification:* as Christian commented, the function call, and the use of stack will have to be changed as well of course (since now it's a pointer to pointer...)

Comment: Note that you will need to modify your method call to `FreeStack(&stack);` for this to work, and change all dereferences to double dereferences (`(*stack)->count` and such)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But before I check your answer, my other question was, how was I able to free the memory if I was just passing by value? Also, the stackADT type is defined as a pointer to a structure called stackCDT. This is a little confusing for me, I come from a C++ and Java background.

Comment: you freed stackCDT with the pointer you passed to the function, but since you didn't give the address of the pointer to the function, you weren't able to change the pointer's original value, but only the copy of it. Still the copy you passed was a pointer to valid allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing that `stackADT` object (pointer) by value in your pop method:

```
void FreeStack(stackADT stack)
```

So `stack` refers to the local copy of that pointer. When you set that pointer = NULL, you modify it only within FreeStack. The main method has its own copy of said pointer, not pointing to NULL.

Comment: Yes, but the free() function will do its job. The occupied memory is still set "free". The stack object will only hold a reference to the free-d memory address; the ownership is still lost.